# How to access individual element of a grid view?

Tags: android

I have created a Grid View without using Adapter.I want to access the individual element of Grid View.How can i do that.I have used following way to create a grid and insert value to individual grid View  it.Please help me how can i do that...

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        one=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.one);
        two=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.two);
        three=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.three);

        btn_check=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_check);

        btn_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                checkSubmit();

            }
        });

        mGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
        //  mGrid.setOnDragListener(new DragListener());
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                info = one.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("click item===="+info);

                System.out.println("position of 1"+pos);

               /* TextView textView = (TextView) itemView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(textViewValues[position]);*/
            }
        });
        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                info = two.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                info = three.getText().toString();

            }
        });
         inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < NBR_ITEMS; i++) {
            final View  itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, mGrid, false);
            final TextView text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

           // String values=text.getText().toString();
            //    System.out.println("value at 0=="+values);


            System.out.println("child at position====");

            if ((i == 4)) {
                itemView.setEnabled(false);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

                text.setText("3");

                System.out.println("vbdkvjubys"+text);
                text.setPadding(60,30,10,10);

            }
            if ((i == 3)) {
               itemView.setEnabled(false);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

                text.setText("1");
                text.setPadding(60,30,10,10);

                //   text.setClickable(false);

            }
            if ((i == 7)) {
                itemView.setEnabled(false);
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
                text.setText("2");
                text.setPadding(60,30,10,10);
            }


            final int size = mGrid.getChildCount();
            System.out.println("size===" + size);

            final int finalI = i;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ced1"));

                    itemView.setTag(new Integer(finalI));
                    Integer position = (Integer)view.getTag();
                    itemView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
                    clickedPosition=position;


                    text.setText(info);
                    text.setPadding(60,30,10,10);
                    info="";

                    System.out.println("position clicked==="+clickedPosition);

                    System.out.println("click on cell");
                }
            });



            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
          //  info.replace(info,"");


            //  itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new LongPressListener());

            mGrid.getChildAt(4);

            System.out.println("chld value at position=="+ mGrid.getChildAt(4));


            mGrid.addView(itemView);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code samples of creating the GridView

Comment: @ Prokash i have posted my code .

Comment: Instead of adding setOnClickListener() event for "itemView" can you try with its child view like the "text" ?